# javascript not working from notepad++

Tags: javascript, html, footer

I am having trouple with my javaScript not running in Waterfox for a standard .html file i made using notepad++

Below is my JavaScript

```
document.getElementByID("foot01").innerHTML = "<p>;  " + new Data().getFullYear() + " Extra Technical, Out of this world.</p>";
```

and below is the section of HTML in my file that calls this Jscript

```
<footer id="foot01"></footer>
</div>
<script type="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

What is the issue here and how can i fix it, i made sure that all is spelt correctly and still cant figure it out.

Comment: "made sure that all is spelt correctly" — No you didn't. `ID` should be `Id`

Comment: use `document.getElementById` and `new Date().getFullYear()`

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> <script type="javascript" src="script.js"></script>
>               ^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

That is not a MIME type. It should be `application/javascript` (or `text/javascript` for compatibility with older browsers). But the `type` attribute is optional, so just remove it entirely as the only purpose it serves (when you are writing JS) is to allow you make typos that break the script.

A [validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) should have picked that up.

> ```
> getElementByID
> ```

That is not how you spell `Id`, which needs a lower-case `d`. JavaScript is case sensitive.

> ```
> Data().getFullYear()
> ```

That is not how you spell `Date`, which ends in an `e` not an `a`.

Answer (score 0):

use : new Date().getFullYear()

not new data()

Answer (score 0):

You made two of those mistakes. Correct those two and it will work smooth.

```
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML = "<p>" + new Date().getFullYear() + " Extra Technical, Out of this world.</p>";
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/5j1w12vk/

To identify these issues, you should open developer tools in browser window. You will get clear definition of errors in console. That will save your time to resolve small mistakes.